# How to create multipage app with Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to create a multi-page website using Angular in front-end. I can implement it using routing. But my problem is, **I want to have separate meta tags for each page in the head section.**

So can you provide me some insights on how to add separate meta tags for each individual pages of my Angular application?

**Edit 1: (Responding to the moderators call of question too broad)**

> I want to create a hospital listing website. For each listing in detail view I want to add meta tag containing some customized details from database for Search Engine Optimization. So I wanted to know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Meta` class is a service in Angular to get, add, update and remove HTML meta tags. Meta has following methods.

```
addTag(): Adds one meta tag.
addTags(): Adds more than one meta tag.
getTag(): Returns HTMLMetaElement for the given meta attribute selector.
getTags(): Returns array of HTMLMetaElement for the given meta attribute selector.
updateTag(): Updates meta tag.
removeTag(): Removes meta tag for the given attribute selector.
removeTagElement(): Removes meta tag for the given HTMLMetaElement.
```

To use Meta class, import it from @angular/platform-browser library.

`import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

You can find more about this package on [this](https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-meta-service-for-meta-tags) link and [this](https://alligator.io/angular/meta-tags/) link